# JAXB: How to ommit properties of parent class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is implementation of my class, I'm trying to produce XML out of it

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name="invoice")
public class InvoiceResource extends ResourceSupport {  
  Long invID;
  Float Price;
  PurchaseOrderResource purchaseOrder;
}
```

Output I'm getting is

```
 <invoice xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
      <atom:link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8080/rest/invoices/13"/>
    <atom:_link rel="processInvoice" href="http://localhost:8080/rest/invoices/13">
        <method>POST</method>
    </atom:_link>
    <id>13</id>
    <dueDate>2014-09-24T03:00:00+03:00</dueDate>
    <total>750.0</total>
</invoice>
```

Desired output is

```
 <invoice>
    <link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8080/rest/invoices/13"/>
    <id>13</id>
    <dueDate>2014-09-24T03:00:00+03:00</dueDate>
    <total>750.0</total>
</invoice>
```

I can't annotate ResourceSupport with @XmlTransient

Comment: Are you using JAXB (as per title and tag), or Jackson (as per your annotations)?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan thanks for noticing I've edited the post, and I'm using JAXB

Comment: waht is your ResourceSupport?

Comment: @user23123412 ResourceSupport is a parent class from import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport;